# How to use Azure Search SDK to filter on specific column

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Search and I want to make a simple filter expression using Azure Search SDK, however I cant find documentation in how to do it by code when I want to filter on a specific field.

This work on the Search explorer

[image]

However, in Code, this doesnt work;

I get a syntax error:

```
Console.Write("Apply a filter to the index to find roles  with a rolename:Usuario, ");
            Console.WriteLine("and return the id and name:\n");

            parameters =
                new SearchParameters()
                {
                    Filter = "RoleName:Partner",
                    Select = new[] { "id", "RoleName" }
                };

            results = indexClient.Documents.Search<Role>("*", parameters);

            WriteDocuments(results);
```

The code is based on this sample:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/DotNetHowTo/DotNetHowTo/Program.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
new SearchParameters()
    {
        Filter = "RoleName eq 'Partner'",
        Select = new[] { "id", "RoleName" }
    };
```

Generally speaking, since the SDK is open source, you can use the unit tests on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/search/Microsoft.Azure.Search/tests/Tests/SearchTests.cs#L741) to find examples on how to use some of the more common features.

Comment: Thanks @Ramero, its still not clear to me how to use this for a contains, on the documentation for the REST API  here:https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/azure/search/search-query-odata-filter, I see the .ismatch. The example provided above by you will only search exact matches, and I am looking for  the contains syntax, which I didnt find in the unit tests, nor the sdk samples.

Comment: nevermind, I found I can use searc.ismatch('Partner','RoleName'), works great!